# openGL: What is the order of transformations using glm?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I loaded an object from a .obj file.
I am trying to apply a `glm::rotate, glm::translate, glm::scale` to it.

The movement (translation and rotation) is made using keyboard input like this;

```
// speed is 10
// angle starts at 0
if (keys[UP]) {
    movex += speed * sin(angle);
    movez += speed * cos(angle);
}
if (keys[DOWN]) {
    movex -= speed * sin(angle);
    movez -= speed * cos(angle);
}
if (keys[RIGHT]) {
    angle -= PI / 180;
}
if (keys[LEFT]) {
    angle += PI / 180;
}
```

and then, the transformations:

```
// use shader
glUseProgram(gl_program_shader);

// send the uniform matrices to the shader
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "model_matrix"), 1, false, glm::value_ptr(model_matrix));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "view_matrix"), 1, false, glm::value_ptr(view_matrix));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "projection_matrix"), 1, false, glm::value_ptr(projection_matrix));

glm::mat4 rotate    = glm::rotate(model_matrix, angle, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(model_matrix, glm::vec3(RADIUS + movex, 0, -RADIUS + movez));
glm::mat4 scale     = glm::scale(model_matrix, glm::vec3(20.0, 20.0, 20.0));

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "model_matrix"), 1, false, glm::value_ptr(translate * scale * rotate));
glBindVertexArray(ironMan->vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ironMan->num_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

If I don't use KEY_RIGHT / KEY_LEFT, it works as expected (which means that it translates the object forward and backward). 
If I use them, it rotates around it's own center, but when I press KEY_UP / KEY_DOWN, it translates ... well, not as expected.

I've put on the notifyKeyPressed() function a case to print out the movex, movey and angle value and it seems that the angle is not the one that it should:

- when the IronMan is with it's back at me, angle = 0 - this is the
  start point;
- when the IronMan is with his face on the right, the
  angle should be around -PI / 2 (-1.57), but it is around -80/-90.

I thought this was because of the `glm::scale`, but I changed the values and nothing changed.

Any idea why is the angle acting like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rotation center stays at the origin, you need to translate the rotation center of your object to the origin, make your scale, rotation, translate back, then translate.

**EDIT**
More importantly related to your exact problem, ***glm::rotate*** works in **degrees**.

Comment: So you mean that I need something like `glm::mat4 translate_back = glm::translate(model_matrix, glm::vec3(-RADIUS - prev_movex, 0, +RADIUS - prev_movez));` and then edit the glUniformMatrix4fv function to become:   `glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "model_matrix"), 1, false, glm::value_ptr(translate * translate_back * scale * rotate));` ?

Comment: more like :

translate_rotation_center_to_origin * rotate * scale * translate_origin_to_rotation_center * translation

Comment: first: translate_rotation_center_to_origin is the same as my translate_back right? And couldn't I combine translate_origin_to_rotation_center and translation in one? (that's what I thought I did anyway) ... if not, could you tell how this matrices should look?

Comment: not at all. Never mind the rotation center to origin and back... just multiply your matrices in that order: rotation * scaling * translation

Comment: Now the object dissapeares. I still think the problem it's related to the angle too.

Comment: scale * rotation * translation is the proper order, not rotation * scaling * translation.

Comment: It's still not showing the object (scale * rotation * translation).

Comment: @Jean-Simon you're right, glm::rotate works in degrees. Thanks! (But still, the object is not there)

Comment: Damn :) I'm assuming your clipping planes are correctly set? Try with really small transformations and check what is going on.

Comment: Well, now it works, (not with the order of transformation you've given, but with my own: translate * scale * rotate). All I have done was to change the angle in degrees in the `glm::rotate`. Are you sure that _scale * rotate * translate_ is the right one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42607/discussion-between-jean-simon-brochu-and-tase92)